Pressure of water in a pipe submerged in a draining tank
(please refer to diagram at the bottom)
I'm trying to figure out the efflux speed at Point 4 when water flows out through a submerged pipe.

From point 1 to 2, my thought process is that since not all water goes through the pipe, we cannot use the continuity equation to determine the velocity at point 2. Then, to determine $v_2$ using Bernoulli's equation, would it be as follows? The assumption is that $P_1=P_2$ and  $v_1=0$, but I am unsure whether $P_1=P_2$ is true.

$$\rho gh_1=\frac{1}{2} \rho v_2^2$$

At point 3, can we assume that the velocity of water is zero, similar to how stagnation pressure is determined in a pitot tube? If not, would it be the case that velocity is constant throughout the pipe? My understanding was that water accelerates through the pipe as that is the logic behind dynamic pressure.

Any comments or guidance would be greatly appreciated, thank you.


The velocity is NOT zero at point 3.  In the real world that corner would be rounder and there would be some small loss of velocity, but you are supposed to ignore that.
That's a funny thing about textbook problems.  Sometimes they are unclear about certain points.  So that people who are familiar with the subject can understand what is being asked.  But people who are trying to learn get (understandably) tripped up by smaller details.

The velocities at points 2, 3, and 4 are all the same. The pressures at points 1 and 4 are atmospheric, so the velocity at point 4 is given by $$\frac{1}{2}\rho v_4^2=\rho g (h_1-h_4)$$Point 2 is right inside the pipe, and there is a converging flow entrance effect into the pipe, so the so the pressure at point 2 is below atmospheric. So the pressure at point 2 (just inside the pipe) is $$P_2=\rho g (h_1-h_2)-\frac{1}{2}\rho v_2^2=-\rho g (h_2-h_4) $$These two equations show that $$v_2=v_4$$

It does not matter if you have a tube in the water or just the opening at 4, as long as the tube is not too small. The velocity in all the tube is the same, otherwise there would be a vacuum at some place.The velocity is determined by the high of the water over the opening 4, so the difference between 1 and 4.
